# JsTree .get_checked function doesn't work... help....?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jstree

I'm using JSTree and checkbox plugin, but I couldn't managed to pick the nodes selected (checked), I read in the JSTree documentation about the event .get_checked, but do not know how to implement it, neither the place to put it, if within the function where data is loaded or not, also I don't understand that when the event works, ie I do not know if the event is executed each time a node is checked or have an array that is filled every time a node is chcked... please help me ... the truth I'm lost and do not know how to do that.

Here's my Jscript code, the load of data is fine, but the get_checked function doesn't work...

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo2")
        .jstree({
             plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "crrm"],
                   "json_data": {
                    "ajax": {
                        "type": "POST",
                        "url": "/Ubicacion/Arbol/",
                        "data": function (n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0} }
                }
            }

            })

        .bind("check_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
            alert($.jstree._focused().get_checked().attr('id'));
        })

    });
```

Searching around internet I found a "middle" solution:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#demo2")
        .jstree({

            plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "crrm"],
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "/Ubicacion/GetTreeview/",
                    "data": function (n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0} }
                }
            }
        }).bind('check_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            alert("Nodo elegido " + data.rslt.obj.attr("id"));
        });
    });
```

I add these lines:

```
.bind('check_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                alert("Nodo elegido " + data.rslt.obj.attr("id"));
            });
```

and now I had only the parent node, the children doesn't be coleected... any idea..??

please... help me...!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I call/get all checked nodes

`checked =  $("#tree").jstree("get_checked",null,true) ;`

Works nicely for me. It seems to me that the 'trouble' would be when and how you call `.get_checked`

Could you tell us what you want to achieve? The best would be if you can provide sample on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

## Update

Working sample is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/eHJ5v/4/)

1) how you bind action to checking the checkbox

```
$("#jstree").bind('check_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    $("#list").append('<BR>clicked and ' + node_is_check(data));
});
```

2) how to check if a checkbox is checked, where object = data from above

```
object.inst.is_checked(object.rslt.obj
```

Comment: Ok, I need to get the checked nodes of the tree to send to the controller, there I use the ids collected to do an db query. I don`t have the code with me right now, I would post it later...

Comment: well if its posible I need to be triggered every time a checkbox is checked.... or I could use a button for trigger...

Comment: Hi again Radek, I post the code finally in jsfiddle, you can foun in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/DrY2n/

Comment: Radek could you help me with an example..??

Comment: @verofairy: your jsfiddle doesn't work. I provided mine, hope it helps. Check the update.

Comment: thanks Radek....!! but i still have the problem... I couldn't get the all items checked, only the parent... for example I had the parent A, this have children: a1, a2, a3, if I check the checkbox of the A node the result I need is: A, a1, a2, a3